# rsync does not work in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I have created a simple CMake project from the template provided in visual studio 2019. It connects to remote Linux server and errors out while copying a file using "rsync" with the following error.

```
Could not start the 'rsync' command on the remote host, please install it using your system package manager. Please see https://aka.ms/AA23jat for troubleshooting.
```

**The log shows the error details as following.**

```
23:03:25.2045083 [Error, Thread 88]    liblinux.IO.Rsync: liblinux.IO.RsyncException: Could not create daemon configuration file on remote device ---> liblinux.IO.RsyncException: echo config error:  and error output: Unmatched ".
```

**Please note:** rsync is installed on the remote Linux server and tested it with and without ssh its working.

When I tried to test rsync which is provided by Visual Studio under "C:\Apps\VS2019Pro\Common7\IDE\VC\Linux\bin\rsync\rsync.exe" to sync/copy a file to remote linux server it fails with following error.

```
dup() in/out/err failed
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.3]
```

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Comment: Is rsync actually installed on the remote machine, and is it accessible to the user that's connecting to that machine?

Comment: @mrblewog I tried to test it by try connecting from a windows machine using rsync provided with VS and got the error that I posted in the update.

Comment: @mrblewog does VS internally use rsync binary, which is present locally or uses the remote Linux to sync the directory?

Comment: does VS internally use rsync binary -- that's a good question. Can you connect to the remote machine using something other than VS? For example a SSH session? yes -- you say so below.

Answer (score 1):

Rsync speaks the rsync protocol, which is a client server protocol.
The client you are using needs to talk to a server, which is the rsync binary on the remote server, which doesn't seem to be here.

The message is pretty clear:

```
Could not start the 'rsync' command on the remote host, please install it using your system package manager. Please see https://aka.ms/AA23jat for troubleshooting.
```

You really need to have rsync on your remote server.

Comment: Thanks, The rsync is installed on remote server and I tested with and without ssh it is working. I have updated my post with some more details about my testing with rsync. Request you to please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I installed rsync from source on the target using the default settings which installed it at /usr/local/bin/rsync. [Apparently the path Visual Studio expects is /usr/bin](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/remote-headers-rsync-not-installed-error/1056874#TPIN-N1130845). I created a symbolic link with the command 'ln -s `which rsync` /usr/bin/rsync'